# Regex in Bash Shell

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix

Trying to look through a directory and find files that are in this format 'IMG_0000.abc' then put them in another directory but my solution doesnt produce an error but doesn't do as expected which is to move all files in said format to another directory,

$1 = root/folder/images
$2 = root/folder/copiedimages

```
find $1 -name '^(IMG)[_][0-9]{4}.[a-zA-Z]{3}' -exec cp --backup=numbered -t $2 {} +
```

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working" is too vague. What are `$1` and `$2` in a typical run, what do you expect to happen, and what *does* happen? That said, `-name` takes *patterns*, not regular expressions, and your parameter expansions should be quoted.

Comment: Also, unless the problem is caused by leaving the parameters unquoted, this has nothing to do with `bash`.

Comment: @chepner edited it

Comment: `find "$1" -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/IMG_[0-9]{4}\.[a-zA-Z]{3}$' -exec cp --backup=numbered -t "$2" {} +`

Comment: @anubhava worked perfectly! thanks.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with bash.